# Why did not I do this sooner?

Tags: negation

I read some philosophy stuff about life and found some text with such a sentence at the end:

*Why did not I do this sooner?*

Shouldn't it be

*Why didn't I do this sooner?*

*Why did I not do this sooner?*

If you are interested, this is the source - https://www.saymore.in/letting-go-oftentimes-easier-holding/

Comment: Presumably if the "didn't I" form is acceptable then so is the non-contracted "did not I" form.

Answer (score 1):

[This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Why+did+not+I+do%2C+Why+did+I+not+do&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CWhy%20did%20not%20I%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWhy%20did%20not%20I%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhy%20did%20not%20I%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CWhy%20did%20I%20not%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWhy%20did%20I%20not%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhy%20did%20I%20not%20do%3B%2Cc0) shows that "Why did not I do" is far **more** common than "Why did I not do", at least in its source texts since 1940, and over 10 times as common as of 2000. This surprises me, I would have said that "Why did not I do this sooner?"  " is an old-fashioned form, echoing the language of the King James bible, and of Shakespeare. The inversion of "not" and "I" was once common in formal speech, and I would have said is now rare. But to say that this "is not English" is simply incorrect.

I would nonetheless favor the use of "Why did I not do this sooner?" or in informal contexts "Why didn't I  do this sooner?" except when trying to produce a particular stylistic effect.

Comment: The Ngram stat are a bit misleading, though. When searching for "Why didn't I do", you get the results with the note "Replaced Why didn't I do with Why did not I do to match how we processed the books." This means that you don't know how often the different versions of the phrase appears.

Comment: @Mattias That is a basic problem with Google Ngram (and similar tools). It also doesn't tell you in what way a word pattern appears, nor if it is quoting an archaic text like Shakespeare, nor various other things that a human analyst of a text could. But The usage is common enough that animartco's  answer  *' Why did not I' is definitely not English* is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Looking at the ngram results for matches for 'why did not i do' I can't find a single example of 'why did not i do'  indeed if you do the ngram search with quotes Google fails to find a single example of "why did not i do"

Answer (score -1):

You were probably reading a poor translation or typo. ' Why did not I' is definitely not English. As you say it should be "why did I not" or colloquially "Why didn't I". I've just realised the colloquial is similar to the wrong use. How strange!

Comment: Honestly, I saw it first in a different source in a picture. I thought it was a mistake and decided to find copies of it. Some of them were with "didn't I", others - with "did not I" the same. Welcome to English xD

Comment: Actually I think ' Did not I 'is an archaic form of English syntax. I'm hopeless with dates, but it was a long time ago.

Comment: This is certainly English albiet old-fashioned if not archaic. See my answer for details.